# Maya 2011 network render

Tags: 3d, maya

I have a scene to render. the modeling process did not go as planned and I ended up with way too many polygons in my scene. Is there a way to reduce polygon count with out loosing definition? like an "inverse smooth" if you will?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you want is Mesh > Reduce.

http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2010help/index.html?url=Editing_polygons_Reduce_the_number_of_faces_in_a_mesh.htm,topicNumber=d0e210954

(By definition, you can't remove polygons without losing "definition", but the Reduce command does its best. Like everything else in Maya, you'll probably need to play around with the settings until you get something like what you expect.)